# snapshot data is null, but response is coming in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, snapshot, flutter-futurebuilder

So I am trying to get data from API and display it in listview but I can see in logs response is coming but when comes to snapshot it has no data and so circular indicator keeps on rotating. Don't know where the error is. here is the open API that I used `https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10` I'm new to flutter please anyone help me. Thanks in advance.[image]

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'api_provider/api_services.dart';
import 'model/user_data/users_data_response.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "User List",
      home: UsersDetails(title:"User List"),
    );
  }
}

class UsersDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const UsersDetails({Key? key,this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String? title;

  @override
  _UsersDetailsState createState() => _UsersDetailsState();
}

class _UsersDetailsState extends State<UsersDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title!),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<UsersData>(
          future: fetchUsersData(),
          builder: ( context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index ){
                    return Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 30.0,
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index]['picture']['large'])),
                              title: Text((snapshot.data[index]['name']['first'])),
                              subtitle: Text((snapshot.data[index]['location']['city'])),
                              trailing: Text((snapshot.data[index]['dob']['age'])),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              );
            }
            else{
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

user_data_response.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

UsersData usersDataFromJson(String str) => UsersData.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String usersDataToJson(UsersData data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UsersData {
  UsersData({
    this.results,
    this.info,
  });

  List<Result>? results;
  Info? info;

  factory UsersData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UsersData(
    results: json["results"] == null ? null : List<Result>.from(json["results"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
    info: json["info"] == null ? null : Info.fromJson(json["info"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "results": results == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(results!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "info": info == null ? null : info!.toJson(),
  };
}

class Info {
  Info({
    this.seed,
    this.results,
    this.page,
    this.version,
  });

  String? seed;
  int? results;
  int? page;
  String? version;

  factory Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Info(
    seed: json["seed"] == null ? null : json["seed"],
    results: json["results"] == null ? null : json["results"],
    page: json["page"] == null ? null : json["page"],
    version: json["version"] == null ? null : json["version"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "seed": seed == null ? null : seed,
    "results": results == null ? null : results,
    "page": page == null ? null : page,
    "version": version == null ? null : version,
  };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    this.gender,
    this.name,
    this.location,
    this.email,
    this.login,
    this.dob,
    this.registered,
    this.phone,
    this.cell,
    this.id,
    this.picture,
    this.nat,
  });

  Gender? gender;
  Name? name;
  Location? location;
  String? email;
  Login? login;
  Dob? dob;
  Dob? registered;
  String? phone;
  String? cell;
  Id? id;
  Picture? picture;
  String? nat;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
    gender: json["gender"] == null ? null : genderValues.map![json["gender"]],
    name: json["name"] == null ? null : Name.fromJson(json["name"]),
    location: json["location"] == null ? null : Location.fromJson(json["location"]),
    email: json["email"] == null ? null : json["email"],
    login: json["login"] == null ? null : Login.fromJson(json["login"]),
    dob: json["dob"] == null ? null : Dob.fromJson(json["dob"]),
    registered: json["registered"] == null ? null : Dob.fromJson(json["registered"]),
    phone: json["phone"] == null ? null : json["phone"],
    cell: json["cell"] == null ? null : json["cell"],
    id: json["id"] == null ? null : Id.fromJson(json["id"]),
    picture: json["picture"] == null ? null : Picture.fromJson(json["picture"]),
    nat: json["nat"] == null ? null : json["nat"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "gender": gender == null ? null : genderValues.reverse![gender],
    "name": name == null ? null : name!.toJson(),
    "location": location == null ? null : location!.toJson(),
    "email": email == null ? null : email,
    "login": login == null ? null : login!.toJson(),
    "dob": dob == null ? null : dob!.toJson(),
    "registered": registered == null ? null : registered!.toJson(),
    "phone": phone == null ? null : phone,
    "cell": cell == null ? null : cell,
    "id": id == null ? null : id!.toJson(),
    "picture": picture == null ? null : picture!.toJson(),
    "nat": nat == null ? null : nat,
  };
}

class Dob {
  Dob({
    this.date,
    this.age,
  });

  DateTime? date;
  int? age;

  factory Dob.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Dob(
    date: json["date"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
    age: json["age"] == null ? null : json["age"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "date": date == null ? null : date!.toIso8601String(),
    "age": age == null ? null : age,
  };
}

enum Gender { FEMALE, MALE }

final genderValues = EnumValues({
  "female": Gender.FEMALE,
  "male": Gender.MALE
});

class Id {
  Id({
    this.name,
    this.value,
  });

  String? name;
  String? value;

  factory Id.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Id(
    name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
    value: json["value"] == null ? null : json["value"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name == null ? null : name,
    "value": value == null ? null : value,
  };
}

class Location {
  Location({
    this.street,
    this.city,
    this.state,
    this.country,
    this.postcode,
    this.coordinates,
    this.timezone,
  });

  Street? street;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? country;
  dynamic postcode;
  Coordinates? coordinates;
  Timezone? timezone;

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location(
    street: json["street"] == null ? null : Street.fromJson(json["street"]),
    city: json["city"] == null ? null : json["city"],
    state: json["state"] == null ? null : json["state"],
    country: json["country"] == null ? null : json["country"],
    postcode: json["postcode"],
    coordinates: json["coordinates"] == null ? null : Coordinates.fromJson(json["coordinates"]),
    timezone: json["timezone"] == null ? null : Timezone.fromJson(json["timezone"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "street": street == null ? null : street!.toJson(),
    "city": city == null ? null : city,
    "state": state == null ? null : state,
    "country": country == null ? null : country,
    "postcode": postcode,
    "coordinates": coordinates == null ? null : coordinates!.toJson(),
    "timezone": timezone == null ? null : timezone!.toJson(),
  };
}

class Coordinates {
  Coordinates({
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
  });

  String? latitude;
  String? longitude;

  factory Coordinates.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Coordinates(
    latitude: json["latitude"] == null ? null : json["latitude"],
    longitude: json["longitude"] == null ? null : json["longitude"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "latitude": latitude == null ? null : latitude,
    "longitude": longitude == null ? null : longitude,
  };
}

class Street {
  Street({
    this.number,
    this.name,
  });

  int? number;
  String? name;

  factory Street.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Street(
    number: json["number"] == null ? null : json["number"],
    name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "number": number == null ? null : number,
    "name": name == null ? null : name,
  };
}

class Timezone {
  Timezone({
    this.offset,
    this.description,
  });

  String? offset;
  String? description;

  factory Timezone.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Timezone(
    offset: json["offset"] == null ? null : json["offset"],
    description: json["description"] == null ? null : json["description"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "offset": offset == null ? null : offset,
    "description": description == null ? null : description,
  };
}

class Login {
  Login({
    this.uuid,
    this.username,
    this.password,
    this.salt,
    this.md5,
    this.sha1,
    this.sha256,
  });

  String? uuid;
  String? username;
  String? password;
  String? salt;
  String? md5;
  String? sha1;
  String? sha256;

  factory Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Login(
    uuid: json["uuid"] == null ? null : json["uuid"],
    username: json["username"] == null ? null : json["username"],
    password: json["password"] == null ? null : json["password"],
    salt: json["salt"] == null ? null : json["salt"],
    md5: json["md5"] == null ? null : json["md5"],
    sha1: json["sha1"] == null ? null : json["sha1"],
    sha256: json["sha256"] == null ? null : json["sha256"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "uuid": uuid == null ? null : uuid,
    "username": username == null ? null : username,
    "password": password == null ? null : password,
    "salt": salt == null ? null : salt,
    "md5": md5 == null ? null : md5,
    "sha1": sha1 == null ? null : sha1,
    "sha256": sha256 == null ? null : sha256,
  };
}

class Name {
  Name({
    this.title,
    this.first,
    this.last,
  });

  Title? title;
  String? first;
  String? last;

  factory Name.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Name(
    title: json["title"] == null ? null : titleValues.map![json["title"]],
    first: json["first"] == null ? null : json["first"],
    last: json["last"] == null ? null : json["last"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "title": title == null ? null : titleValues.reverse![title],
    "first": first == null ? null : first,
    "last": last == null ? null : last,
  };
}

enum Title { MS, MR, MRS }

final titleValues = EnumValues({
  "Mr": Title.MR,
  "Mrs": Title.MRS,
  "Ms": Title.MS
});

class Picture {
  Picture({
    this.large,
    this.medium,
    this.thumbnail,
  });

  String? large;
  String? medium;
  String? thumbnail;

  factory Picture.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Picture(
    large: json["large"] == null ? null : json["large"],
    medium: json["medium"] == null ? null : json["medium"],
    thumbnail: json["thumbnail"] == null ? null : json["thumbnail"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "large": large == null ? null : large,
    "medium": medium == null ? null : medium,
    "thumbnail": thumbnail == null ? null : thumbnail,
  };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T>? map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String>? get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map!.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

api_services.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:api_usage/model/user_data/users_data_response.dart';

final String api ="https://randomuser.me/api/?results=";
int userCount=10;

Future<UsersData> fetchUsersData() async {
  final request=api+userCount.toString();
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(request));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final result = json.decode(response.body);
    debugPrint("result-----${result}");
    return result['results'];
  }
  else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load UsersData');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you do not account for an error in the snapshot. Everything that is not snapshot.hasData causes the spinner to go off in your case right now. Add another test for if (snapshot.hasError) and properly handle it, this should get you on the right path. Hint: you are not returning UsersData as promised in the FutureBuilder.

**UPD:**

Also be aware that due to the nature of how widgets work, FutureBuilder can be rebuilt, which will cause your fetch function to be called multiple times. You may want to avoid doing that.

**UPD 2:**

To expand on what I said above. Within you FutureBuilder you only verify if the snapshot.hasData and in ANY other case you show the indicator, which goes both for (1) snapshot not having any data or (2) snapshot having an error.

Try to add another if condition to catch and handle the error, like so:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return ...
} else if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return ...
} else {
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

This second condition should be enough to move you forward with the code.

Comment: Thanks @jabbson,but I didn’t understand it exactly and I am kinda new to flutter could you please edit the code where I made mistake so I can understand it and will be helpful for me 

Comment: Added another update to the answer, sorry if I wasn't clear at first with my explanation.